# How to separate Android signedData into separate strings in php

Tags: php, android, eclipse

So I have in-app-billing working with PHP server verify. However, I cant figure out how to separate my signed data Strings into separate strings in PHP. When I echo $signedData in PHP I get the following.

```
{\"nonce\":4658477652655443541,\"orders\":[{\"notificationId\":\"android.test.purchased\",\"orderId\":\"transactionId.android.test.purchased\",\"packageName\":\"com.coolboy.coolapp\",\"productId\":\"android.test.purchased\",\"purchaseTime\":1350913071409,\"purchaseState\":0}]}
```

How do you separate the nonce, orders, and etc. in PHP to separate variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode the string into an object.

This code:

```
$str = "{\"nonce\":4658477652655443541,\"orders\":[{\"notificationId\":\"android.test.purchased\",\"orderId\":\"transactionId.android.test.purchased\",\"packageName\":\"com.coolboy.coolapp\",\"productId\":\"android.test.purchased\",\"purchaseTime\":1350913071409,\"purchaseState\":0}]}";
$json = json_decode($str);
var_dump($json);
```

Produces:

```
class stdClass#1 (2) {
  public $nonce =>
  double(4.6584776526554E+18)
  public $orders =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    class stdClass#2 (6) {
      public $notificationId =>
      string(22) "android.test.purchased"
      public $orderId =>
      string(36) "transactionId.android.test.purchased"
      public $packageName =>
      string(19) "com.coolboy.coolapp"
      public $productId =>
      string(22) "android.test.purchased"
      public $purchaseTime =>
      double(1350913071409)
      public $purchaseState =>
      int(0)
    }
  }
}
```

And of course you can do:

```
$nonce = $json->nonce;
$notificationId = $json->orders[0]->notificationId;
// etc...
```

More info on JSON:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON (less technical)
- http://www.json.org/ (more technical)

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the examples. However do you know how I could convert the purchaseTime to Timestamp? or tell me what format the current purchaseTime is in?

Comment: Actually, the output I showed already does: `double(1350913071409)`. It's a `double`.

Answer (score 2):

That's JSON.

```
$array = json_decode($var);
```